# Activated route is not finding my queryParams

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get a param in my route, but when i try to print it, is returning undefined in my console.

This is my routing module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':id',
    component: ListaDadosPvSelecionadoComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
];
```

this is how i'm trying to get the params:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params) => console.log(params['id']));
}
```

when i go to `route/3` my component is being rendered but i get:

> undefined

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`params` and `queryParams` are two different things.

Params are part of URL `/page/123`

Query params are GET parameters `/page?id=123`

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params) => console.log(params.id));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Query param works for `/domain?id=value`

You can use `snapshot.paramMap` for routes param .

```
   this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
```

Comment: it work, can you explain why queryParams is don't working but paramMap.get() works?

Comment: Query param works for /domain?id=value you need to use snapshot.paramMap for routing id @veroneseComS